# How do I deploy a specific revision of a charm?

Tags: juju

I am trying to deploy a charm, `mongodb` with the following:

```
juju deploy mongodb
```

but the newest revision introduced a bug, or for some other reason I want to deploy an older version of the charm, how can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

First off, you need to find out which revision you need. The revision of the *charm* is completely different from the *bzr revision*. So for https://jujucharms.com/precise/mongodb/

[image]

So the *charm revision* is 26. Now let's say you think something broke in 26, and you want to try version 25 or earlier.

```
juju deploy cs:mongodb-25
```

will give you that revision of the charm. However it is always a good idea to be explicit about the series as well to ensure repeatability:

```
juju deploy cs:precise/mongodb-25
```